# select columns from second row add to the end of the first row in sql group by ID

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql

I have a table customer in the database as below.

```
ID  UID  Address1  Name  code
10  5    A         Jac   683501
11  5    B         Joe   727272
13  6    C         mat   373737
```

first two records (10,11) have a common uID -5 . These two records can be considered as a single unit.
fourth record is having a separate UID , so it is a separate unit

I need to produce an output in a csv file such a way that

```
ID  UID Name  code     Address1  Name2  Code2
10  5   jac   683501   A         Joe    727272 
13  6   mat   373737   C
```

Name2 and code2 values are from the second row, since UID is same for first two records, we can considered it as a single unit.

Can anyone give hints to query for generating these records.

Comment: You can do this with a [pivot](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177410(v=sql.105).aspx).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This process to transform data from rows into columns is known as a PIVOT. There are several ways that this can be done.

You can use a `row_number()` along with an aggregate function with a CASE expression:

```
select min(id),
  uid,
  max(case when seq = 1 then name end) Name,
  max(case when seq = 1 then code end) Code,
  max(case when seq = 1 then Address1 end) Address1,
  max(case when seq = 2 then name end) Name2,
  max(case when seq = 2 then code end) code2,
  max(case when seq = 2 then Address1 end) Address1_2
from
(
  select id, uid, address1, name, code,
    row_number() over(partition by uid order by id) seq
  from yourtable
) d
group by uid;
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/bb116e/3).

You could use both the UNPIVOT and the PIVOT function:

```
select id, uid,
  name1, code1, address1, name2, code2, address2
from 
(
  select id, uid, col+cast(seq as varchar(10)) col, value
  from
  (
    select 
      (select min(id) 
       from yourtable t2
       where t.uid = t2.uid) id, 
      uid, 
      cast(address1 as varchar(20)) address, 
      cast(name as varchar(20)) name, 
      cast(code as varchar(20)) code,
      row_number() over(partition by uid order by id) seq
    from yourtable t
  ) d
  unpivot
  (
    value
    for col in (address, name, code)
  ) unpiv
) src
pivot
(
  max(value)
  for col in (name1, code1, address1, name2, code2, address2)
) piv;
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/bb116e/15).

Finally if you have an unknown number of values for each `uid`, then you can use dynamic SQL to get the result:

```
DECLARE @cols AS NVARCHAR(MAX),
    @query  AS NVARCHAR(MAX)

select @cols = STUFF((SELECT ',' + QUOTENAME(col+(cast(seq as varchar(10)))) 
                    from
                    (
                      select row_number() over(partition by uid order by id) seq
                      from yourtable
                    ) d
                    cross apply
                    (
                      select 'name', 1 union all
                      select 'code', 2 union all
                      select 'address', 3 
                    ) c (col, so)
                    group by seq, col, so
                    order by seq, so
            FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE
            ).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)') 
        ,1,1,'')

set @query = 'SELECT id, uid,' + @cols + ' 
            from 
            (
                select id, uid, col+cast(seq as varchar(10)) col, value
                from
                (
                  select 
                    (select min(id) 
                     from yourtable t2
                     where t.uid = t2.uid) id, 
                    uid, 
                    cast(address1 as varchar(20)) address, 
                    cast(name as varchar(20)) name, 
                    cast(code as varchar(20)) code,
                    row_number() over(partition by uid order by id) seq
                  from yourtable t
                ) d
                unpivot
                (
                  value
                  for col in (address, name, code)
                ) unpiv
            ) x
            pivot 
            (
                max(value)
                for col in (' + @cols + ')
            ) p '

execute(@query);
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/bb116e/18). All versions will give a result:

```
| ID | UID | NAME1 |  CODE1 | ADDRESS1 |  NAME2 |  CODE2 | ADDRESS2 |
---------------------------------------------------------------------
| 10 |   5 |   Jac | 683501 |        A |    Joe | 727272 |        B |
| 13 |   6 |   mat | 373737 |        C | (null) | (null) |   (null) |
```

Answer (score 1):

Try inner join.

```
select u2.firstname,u2.col2,
from users u
inner join users u2 on u.userid=u2.userid
where u.firstname=u2.lastname
```

Comment: substitute your columns and let me know if you need any help.

Comment: I don't think inner join will work, we cannot join with firstname also